# geom_violin using the weight aesthetic unexpectedly drop levels

Tags: ggplot2, violin-plot, aesthetics

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12345)

dat <- data.frame(year = c(rep(1990, 100), rep(1991, 100), rep(1992, 100)),
                  fish_length = sample(x = seq(from = 10, 131, by = 0.1), 300, replace = F),
                  nb_caught = sample(x = seq(from = 1, 200, by = 0.1), 300, replace = T), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
       mutate(age = ifelse(fish_length < 20, 1,
                           ifelse(fish_length >= 20 & fish_length < 100, 2, 
                                  ifelse(fish_length >= 100 & fish_length < 130, 3, 4)))) %>% 
       arrange(year, fish_length) 

head(dat)
  year fish_length nb_caught age
1 1990        10.1      45.2   1
2 1990        10.7     170.0   1
3 1990        10.9      62.0   1
4 1990        12.1     136.0   1
5 1990        14.1      80.8   1
6 1990        15.0     188.9   1

dat %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(ages = n_distinct(age)) # Only 1992 has age 4 fish
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   year  ages
  <dbl> <int>
1  1990     3
2  1991     3
3  1992     4

dat %>% filter(age == 4) # only 1 row for age 4
  year fish_length nb_caught age
1 1992       130.8      89.2   4
```

Here:

- *year* = year of sampling
- *fish_length* = length of the fish in cm
- *nb_caught* = number of fish caught following the use of an age-length key, hence explaining the presence of decimals
- *age* = age of the fish

## `graph1`: *geom_violin* not using the weight aesthetic.

Here, I got to copy each line of `dat` according to the value found in *nb_caught*.

```
dim(dat) # 300 rows
dat_graph1 <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), floor(dat$nb_caught)), ]
dim(dat_graph1) # 30932 rows
dat_graph1$nb_caught <- NULL # useless now
sum(dat$nb_caught) - nrow(dat_graph1) # 128.2 rows lost here
```

Since I have decimal values of *nb_caught*, I took the integer value to create `dat_graph1`. I lost 128.2 "rows" in the process.

Now for the graph:

```
dat_tile <- data.frame(year = sort(unique(dat$year))[sort(unique(dat$year)) %% 2 == 0]) 
# for the figure's background

graph1 <- ggplot(data = dat_graph1, 
                 aes(x = as.factor(year), y = fish_length, fill = as.factor(age), 
                     color = as.factor(age), .drop = F)) +
          geom_tile(data = dat_tile, aes(x = factor(year), y = 1, height = Inf, width = 1),
                    fill = "grey80", inherit.aes = F) +
          geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95), color = "black",
                      scale = "width", position = "dodge") + 
          scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
          labs(x = "Year", y = "Fish length", fill = "Age", color = "Age", title = "graph1") +
          scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", drop = F) + # drop = F for not losing levels
          scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired", drop = F) + # drop = F for not losing levels
          scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = 0.01)) +
          theme_bw()

graph1
```

[graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXX15.png)

Note here that I have a flat bar for *age* 4 in *year* 1992.

```
dat_graph1 %>% filter(year == 1992, age == 4) %>% pull(fish_length) %>% unique
[1] 130.8
```

That is because I only have one length for that particular *year-age* combination.

## `graph2`: *geom_violin* using the weight aesthetic.

Now, instead of copying each row of `dat` by the value of *number_caught*, let's use the weight aesthetic.

Let's calculate the weight *wt* that each line of `dat` will have in the calculation of the density curve of each *year-age* combinations.

```
dat_graph2 <- dat %>%
              group_by(year, age) %>%
              mutate(wt = nb_caught / sum(nb_caught)) %>%
              as.data.frame()
head(dat_graph2)
  year fish_length nb_caught age         wt
1 1990        10.1      45.2   1 0.03573123
2 1990        10.7     170.0   1 0.13438735
3 1990        10.9      62.0   1 0.04901186
4 1990        12.1     136.0   1 0.10750988
5 1990        14.1      80.8   1 0.06387352
6 1990        15.0     188.9   1 0.14932806

graph2 <- ggplot(data = dat_graph2, 
                 aes(x = as.factor(year), y = fish_length, fill = as.factor(age), 
                     color = as.factor(age), .drop = F)) +
          geom_tile(data = dat_tile, aes(x = factor(year), y = 1, height = Inf, width = 1),
                    fill = "grey80", inherit.aes = F) +
          geom_violin(aes(weight = wt), draw_quantiles = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95), color = "black",
                      scale = "width", position = "dodge") + 
          scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
          labs(x = "Year", y = "Fish length", fill = "Age", color = "Age", title = "graph2") +
          scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", drop = F) + # drop = F for not losing levels
          scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired", drop = F) + # drop = F for not losing levels
          scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = 0.01)) + 
          theme_bw()

graph2

dat_graph2 %>% filter(year == 1992, age == 4)
  year fish_length nb_caught age wt
1 1992       130.8      89.2   4  1
```

[graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5WSO.png)

Note here that the flat bar for *age* 4 in *year* 1992 seen on graph1 has been dropped here even though the line exists in dat_graph2.

## My questions

1. Why is the age 4 in 1992 level dropped when using the weight aesthetic? How can I overcome this?
2. Why are the two graphs not visually alike even though they used the same data?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1.

Problem 1 is not related to using the weight aesthetic. You can check this by dropping the weight aesthetic in the code for your second graph. The problem is, that the algorithm for computing the density fails, when there are too less observations.

That is the reason, why group 4 shows up in graph 1 with the expanded dataset (grpah 1). Here you increase the number of observations by replicating the number of obs.

Unfortunately, `geom_violin` gives no warning in your specific case. However, if you filter `dat_graph2` for `age == 4` `geom_violin` gives you the warning

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_ydensity()`:
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

`geom_density` is much clearer on this issue, giving a warning, that groups with less than two obs have been dropped.

Unfortunately, I have no solution to overcome this, besides working with the expanded dataset.

2.

Concerning problem 2 I have no convincing answer except that I guess that this is related to the details of the kernel density estimator used by geom_violin, geom_density, ... and perhaps also somehow related to the number of data points.

Comment: Thanks for your help @stefan. Seeing all these uncertainties with violin plot, I'm now considering plotting raw data instead with bar plots. I think the package *ggridges* could be a good alternative.